# python float64 type conversion issue with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, floating-point

I have a need to convert an 18 digit float64 pandas column to an integer or string to be readable avoiding the exponential notation.
But I am not successful so far.

```
df=pd.DataFrame(data={'col1':[915235514180670190,915235514180670208]},dtype='float64')
print(df)
       col1
0  9.152355e+17
1  9.152355e+17
```

Then I tried converting it to int64. But last 3 digits going wrong.

```
df.col1.astype('int64')
0    915235514180670208
1    915235514180670208
Name: col1, dtype: int64
```

But you see .. the value is goin wrong. Not sure why.
I read from documentation as int64 should be able to hold an 18 digit number.

```
 int64  Integer (-9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807)
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong ?
How can I achieve my requirement ?

Giving further info based on Eric Postpischil comment.
If float64 can't hold 18 digits, I might be in trouble.
Thing is that I get this data through a pandas read_sql function call from DB. And it automatically type casted to float64.
I don't see an option to mention datatype in pandas read_sql()

Any thoughts from any one on what I can do to overcome this problem ?

Comment: A `Float64` cannot represent 915235514180670190. When that decimal numeral is converted to `Float64`, the result is the nearest representable value, 915235514180670208. Converting the `Float64` to decimal cannot reproduce the original value because it is gone.

Comment: Problem is that , I get this data to a float64 through a read_sql from a DB. So, thinking what can I do ?

Comment: You probably want to first figure out whether the database itself holds the information you need, or whether that information was lost when the values were entered into the database. What's the column type of the relevant column of the DB table? If the DB is already using IEEE 754 floating-point for that column then this is an impossible task. If it's using some other floating-point type with higher precision or an integer type then there may be something you can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[read_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html) in Pandas has a `coerce_float` parameter that might help.  It's on by default, and is documented as:

> Attempts to convert values of non-string, non-numeric objects (like decimal.Decimal) to floating point, useful for SQL result sets.

Setting this to `False` helps, e.g. with the following schema/data:

```
import psycopg2

con = psycopg2.connect()

with con, con.cursor() as cur:
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE foo ( id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, num DECIMAL(30,0) )")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO foo (num) VALUES (123456789012345678901234567890)")
```

I can run:

```
print(pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM foo", con))

print(pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM foo", con, coerce_float=False))
```

which gives me the following output:

```
   id           num
0   1  1.234568e+29

   id                             num
0   1  123456789012345678901234567890
```

preserving the precision of the value I inserted.

You've not given many details of the database you're using, but hopefully the above is helpful to somebody!

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that a float64 a mantisse of 53 bits which can represent 15 or 16 decimal digits ([ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Basic_and_interchange_formats)).

That means that *a 18 digit float64 pandas column* is an illusion. No need to go into Pandas not even into numpy types:

```
>>> n = 915235514180670190
>>> d = float(n)
>>> print(n, d, int(d))
915235514180670190 9.152355141806702e+17 915235514180670208
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a work around to deal that problem.. Thought of sharing it as it may help some one else.

```
    #Preapring SQL to extract all rows.
    sql='SELECT * , CAST(col1 AS CHAR(18)) as DUMMY_COL FROM table1;'
    
    #Get data from postgres
    df=pd.read_sql(sql, self.conn)
    
    # converting dummy col to integer
    df['DUMMY_COL']=df['DUMMY_COL'].astype('int64')
    
    # removing the original col1 column with replacing the int64 converted one.
    df['col1'] = df['DUMMY_COL']
    df.drop('DUMMY_COL', axis=1, inplace=True)
```